# Can I copy a google mock object after setting expectations?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I want to add a utility function in my test fixture class that will return a mock with particular expectations/actions set.

E.g.:

```
class MockListener: public Listener
{
    // Google mock method.
};

class MyTest: public testing::Test
{
public:
    MockListener getSpecialListener()
    {
        MockListener special;
        EXPECT_CALL(special, /** Some special behaviour e.g. WillRepeatedly(Invoke( */ );
        return special;
    }
};

TEST_F(MyTest, MyTestUsingSpecialListener)
{
    MockListener special = getSpecialListener();

    // Do something with special.
}
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘MockListener ::MockListener (MockListener &&)’
```

So I assume mocks can't be copied? Why, and if so is there another elegant way to get a function to manufacture a ready-made mock with expectations/actions already set?

Obviously I can make the getSpecialListener return a MockListener&, but then it would unnecessarily need to be a member of MyTest, and since only some of the tests use that particular mock (and I should only populate the mock behaviour if the test is using it) it would be less clean.

Comment: I'd suspect a call expectation refers to a specific mock instance, so these won't be deferred automatically to copies of the mock (would this make sense anyhow?). _"So I assume mocks can't be copied"?_ Mock classes per SE should be copyable IIRC.

Comment: Oops, the following [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/googlemock/GD73UXjQowE) seems to prove my remembrance wrong. Seems any mock objects aren't being copyable.

Comment: Yup, simply removing the MOCK_METHODX and replacing with a regular implementation of the Listener method makes it compile. You're right, that post pretty much explains it. :-(

Comment: And did you try implementing copy behavior yourself explicitly? Though expectations can't be copied along in any way. I'd try using a separate function, to create expectations for arbitrary mock instances to be used in setup.

Comment: My main intention was that the expectations were copied. And the post you mentioned says that they won't be.

Comment: Well, as mentioned provide an extra helper function, that sets up expectations on arbitrary mock instances.

Comment: return via `std::unique_ptr`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mock objects are non-copyable, but you can write a factory method that returns a pointer to a newly created mock object. To simplify the object ownership, you can use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<MockListener> getSpecialListener() {
  MockListener* special = new MockListener();
  EXPECT_CALL(*special, SomeMethod()).WillRepeatedly(DoStuff());
  return std::unique_ptr<MockListener>(special);
}

TEST_F(MyTest, MyTestUsingSpecialListener) {
  std::unique_ptr<MockListener> special = getSpecialListener();

  // Do something with *special.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems not possible [to copy mock class instances](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/googlemock/GD73UXjQowE) properly, especially not deep copying any expectations bound to them.

What you though can do is, to provide helper functions in your test class, that set up specific expectations on mock instances, like:

```
class MyTest: public testing::Test {
public:
    MockListener& setSpecialListenerExpectations(MockListener& special) 
             // ^                                            ^
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(special, /** Some special behaviour e.g.  WillRepeatedly(Invoke( */ );
        return special;
    }
};
```

and make them *special* in your test case:

```
TEST_F(MyTest, MyTestUsingSpecialListener) {
    MockListener special;
    setSpecialListenerExpectations(special);

    // Do something with special.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a mock class that is copyable, but you can write a class that is copyable and refers to a mock object that provides its implementation.

```
class MyMockImpl
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, someMethod, (int arg), (const));
};

template<typename Impl>
class MyCopyableMock
{
public:
    explicit MyCopyableMock(Impl& impl)
        : impl(impl)
    {}
    
    void someMethod(int arg) const
    {
        impl.someMethod(arg);
    }
};

TEST(CopyableMockTest, someMethod_isCalled)
{
    MyMockImpl impl_mock;
    MyCopyableMock<MyMockImpl> mock(impl_mock);
    EXPECT_CALL(impl_mock, someMethod(123)).Times(Exactly(1));
    
    MyCopyableMock copyMock = mock;
    copyMock.someMethod(123);
}
```

Note that for the purpose of mocking, it often doesn't even matter on which instance / copy a mock method is called, so using a single (shared) mock object to mock the behavior of multiple copies is often acceptable. Some care must be taken regarding the order of calls, though, when they are made on multiple copies sharing one implementation object...

This approach can also be used to "track" copy/move construction/assignment and formulate expectations on if/when and how often they are called.