# gmock call to implicitly deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I'm playing with gmock, and I have a contrived example I'm using to learn it's nuances.  I have a problem with a call to what I would have expected the implicit copy constructor:

```
// mock_word.h
class MockWord : Word {
public:
    MockWord(const std::string word) : Word(word) {};
    MOCK_METHOD0(pigLatinify, std::string(void));
};

// strings.h
template <typename Word>
class Strings {
...
private:
    std::vector<Word>* words = new std::vector<Word>();
public:
    // This should call the implicit copy constructor
    void addWord(const Word word) {
        this->words->push_back(word); 
    };
...
};

// strings_test.cpp
class StringsTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    Strings<MockWord>* strings;
public:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        strings = new Strings<MockWord>();
    };
    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete strings;
    };
};

TEST_F(StringsTest, StringIsAllPigLatinifiedNicely) {
    MockWord mockWordA("beast");
    MockWord mockWordB("dough");

    // Set some expectations for the Mock
    EXPECT_CALL(mockWordA, pigLatinify()).Times(AtLeast(1)); 
    EXPECT_CALL(mockWordB, pigLatinify()).Times(AtLeast(1)); 

    strings->addWord(mockWordA);
    strings->addWord(mockWordB);
    ...
};
```

Now, I could probably have this complile and work if I convert `mockWordA` and `mockWordB` from automatic variables to pointers, but that's not the interface I want to provide.

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'MockWord'
    strings->addWord(mockWordA);
                     ^~~~~~~~~
mock_word.h:11:9: note: copy constructor of 'MockWord' is implicitly     deleted because field 'gmock0_pigLatinify_11' has a deleted copy     constructor
    MOCK_METHOD0(pigLatinify, std::string(void));
```

Comment: mocks from google mock are not copyable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I copy a google mock object after setting expectations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043640/can-i-copy-a-google-mock-object-after-setting-expectations)

Comment: So I can only achieve this basic test by making my object a pointer type?  That seems restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing my function interface to `Strings::addWord(Word* word)` which to me seems restrictive given that I'd rather not use pointers with such a basic example.